# Jquery syntax correction

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to get a value of a checked radio button. Based on the checked radio button value (Custom_01, Custom_02, Custom_03) I want to display a string/text in the an input field. Can you please let me know if the below syntax is correct. I tried it and I am not getting the output value in the text box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var selectedDMlabel = $('input:radio[name=FIELD_38]:checked').val();

If(selectedDMlabel == 'Custom_01')
$("input#FIELD_370").val('Excellent');

If(selectedDMlabel == 'Custom_02')
$("input#FIELD_370").val('Very Good');

If(selectedDMlabel == 'Custom_03')
$("input#FIELD_370").val('Fair');

</script>
```

Comment: do it in dom ready handler

Comment: `If` is wrong it is `if`

Comment: Use `if` instead of `If`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic Javascript syntax.

Comment: $("#FIELD_370").val('Fair'); is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `If` should be `if` (*not capitalized*)

And you should wrap all the code in the dom ready event, so it is not executed too soon.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var selectedDMlabel = $('input:radio[name=FIELD_38]:checked').val();

    if(selectedDMlabel == 'Custom_01')
        $("input#FIELD_370").val('Excellent');

    if(selectedDMlabel == 'Custom_02')
        $("input#FIELD_370").val('Very Good');

    if(selectedDMlabel == 'Custom_03')
        $("input#FIELD_370").val('Fair');
});
</script>
```

---

On another note, this code would be better served by a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var selectedDMlabel = $('input:radio[name=FIELD_38]:checked').val();
    var newValue;
    switch(selectedDMlabel){
        case 'Custom_01':
            newValue = 'Excellent';
            break;
        case 'Custom_02':
            newValue = 'Very Good';
            break;
        case 'Custom_03':
            newValue = 'Fair';
            break;
    }
    if (newValue)  $("input#FIELD_370").val(newValue);
});
</script>
```